# Mobile DB for Angular

Tags: android, angular, pouchdb

In developing a stand-alone app for windows and mobile device I was going to use Angular plus a DB.  Instead of indexedDB can I use pouchDB on Angular's SPA app?  Will it be installable as part of the Angular install?  Otherwise I'll need just to use the indexedDB.

Comment: Yes you can use pouchDB in an Angular app. pouchDB uses [adapters](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html) and the default backing store is indexedDB. SQLite is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Angular together with PouchDB to create a installable and offline-capable application. This is then called a [Progressive Web App (PWA)](https://www.violencepreventionnb.org/what-is-pwa-explained-in-simple-terms/). We have done this at the [Aam Digital project](https://github.com/Aam-Digital/ndb-core).
In the end you are hosting a website, but when visiting this website e.g. with the chrome browser you can see an install icon which allows you to install the app on the device.

You need to use and configure [Angular service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) in order to make it installable.

As [@RamblinRose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4964791/ramblinrose) noted, PouchDB uses different backends in order to store data on the local device. In most cases this is the IndexedDB. The biggest benefit is that PouchDB easily lets you setup a synchronization between this local DB and a remote one.